# Web app in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, development

For a school project, I have to make a web application that would run on a kiosk. Where visitors authenticate themselves with their ID card, that prints a sticker with their data read off the ID card, as some sort of entrance key.

In an ideal situation, this should run entirely in SharePoint. There is a browser plugin from the government that allows websites to read an ID card.

I'm wondering if it would be possible to make such a web application inside SharePoint Online?

Comment: Were you instructed that this had to be done in SharePoint...... It seems like a very odd platform to choose for something like this.  You also tagged this as SharePoint Online, I would strongly recommend SharePoint On-Prem for something this highly customized, and even then I would look at some other platform than SharePoint.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment! I have indeed been instructed that this has to be done in a SharePoint Online environment. I agree that this is probably not a good way to execute this. I'm just wondering if it would be possible. Would I be able to create an app to add in SharePoint that can read an ID card?